# How do I use one stored procedure as a "master" so that it invokes another procedure and returns that other procedure's output as its own?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Basically in my "master sproc" I will just check a few of the input parameters to determine which subordinate sproc to call, and then just pass the output of that subordinate sproc back to the caller. Using SQL Server.

Here is code that doesn't work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.master
     @a char(1)
   , @b char(1)
AS
IF @a > @b
    EXEC dbo.proc_a @a, @b;
ELSE
    EXEC dbo.proc_b @a, @b;
GO
```

This code just returns "0", not the results.

Comment: Have you tried writing this proc yet? How far did you get?

Comment: @DavidG I have tried writing the sproc and it just returns "0".

Comment: What do you mean by "return"?

Comment: @DavidG

The subordinate sproc "returns" a table of data. I need that table of data to "pass through" the "master" sproc and get "returned" to the caller, which is like a web service or something so that the data can get to the web page on the other side.

Comment: @DavidG when I execute the subordinate sproc in SSMS I see a big table full of data. When I execute the master sproc I only see the integer "0".

Answer (score 3):

T-SQL code such a "master" proc would be like:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.master
         @a char(1)
       , @b char(1)
    AS
    IF @a > @b
        EXEC dbo.proc_a @a, @b;
    ELSE
        EXEC dbo.proc_b @a, @b;
    GO

Result sets returned by the called procedure will be returned to the client just like if run directly from the master proc.
```

**EDIT:**

Below is an example using the code from your comment:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TransactionsA (col1 int);
INSERT INTO dbo.TransactionsA VALUES(1);
CREATE TABLE dbo.TransactionsB (col1 int);
INSERT INTO dbo.TransactionsB VALUES(2);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetData] 
    @A int = 0
    , @B int = 0 
AS 
IF (@A > @B) 
    EXEC dbo.GetAData @A, @B; 
ELSE 
    EXEC dbo.GetBData @A, @B; 
GO 

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAData] 
    @A int = 0
    , @B int = 0 
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
SELECT * FROM TransactionsA;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetBData] 
    @A int = 0
    , @B int = 0 
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
SELECT * FROM TransactionsB;
GO

EXEC dbo.GetData 1,2; --returns 2
EXEC dbo.GetData 2,1; --returns 1
EXEC dbo.GetData 1,1; --returns 2
GO
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The results are just "0". The data is not present.

@Dan Guzman

Comment: @Infin8Loop, post the code if the called proc and the code you are using to call the master proc.

Comment: ok, how about this:


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetData] 
 @A int = 0,
 @B int = 0
AS
 IF (@A > @B)
  EXEC dbo.GetAData @A, @B;
 ELSE
  EXEC dbo.GetBData @A, @B;  
GO





ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAData] 
 @A int = 0,
 @B int = 0
AS

BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 SELECT * FROM TransactionsA
END





ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetBData] 
 @A int = 0,
 @B int = 0
AS

BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 SELECT * FROM TransactionsB
END

Comment: @Infin8Loop, I added a complete example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are comparing chars but the problem maybe is in you SPs previous definition, I tried the code and is working fine returning data

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetData] 
    @A int = 0, 
    @B int = 0 
AS 
BEGIN
    IF (@A > @B) 
        EXEC dbo.GetAData @A, @B; 
    ELSE 
        EXEC dbo.GetBData @A, @B;   
END
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAData] 
    @A int = 0, 
    @B int = 0 
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    SELECT * FROM [ReportTables].[MyOwnTable1] 
END 
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetBData] 
    @A int = 0, 
    @B int = 0 
AS BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    SELECT * FROM [ReportTables].[MyOwnTable2]
END
```